# How to use Navigator.restorablePushNamed(context, 'our-route-name') with Generated routing in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, state-restoration

I am trying to implement the restorable routing in Flutter. Here is my sample code, that I am trying.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
        switch (settings.name) {
          case 'counter':
            return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const CounterPage());
          default:
            return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>const HomePage());
        }
      },
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      restorationScopeId: "root",
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Home Page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: const Text("Open counter screen"),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.restorablePushNamed(context, 'counter');
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CounterPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const CounterPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Counter"),
      ),
      body: const Center(
        child: Text(
          'Counter Screen',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Note**: Turn on the `Don't keep activities` in developer option of mobile before running the app

**Actual Output**:

1. App starts for the first time. The user goes to the `CounterPage`
2. Then the user switched to any other app ,(i.e. Instagram,Facebook, etc)
3. Now, when user starts our app again then following error occurs

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building _FocusMarker:
Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("counter", null) in the _WidgetsAppState.

Make sure your root app widget has provided a way to generate
this route.
Generators for routes are searched for in the following order:
 1. For the "/" route, the "home" property, if non-null, is used.
 2. Otherwise, the "routes" table is used, if it has an entry for the route.
 3. Otherwise, onGenerateRoute is called. It should return a non-null value for any valid route not handled by "home" and "routes".
 4. Finally if all else fails onUnknownRoute is called.
Unfortunately, onUnknownRoute was not set.
The relevant error-causing widget was
MaterialApp
main.dart:28
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
A GlobalKey was used multiple times inside one widget's child list.
The relevant error-causing widget was
MaterialApp
main.dart:28
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
E/BLASTBufferQueue( 8931): [SurfaceView[com.example.resume_app_routing/com.example.resume_app_routing.MainActivity]#9](f:0,a:2) isEGL=1, mPendingRelease.size()=1, mMaxAcquiredBuffers=4, currentMaxAcquiredBufferCount=2
```

**Expected Output**:

1. App starts for the first time. The user goes to the `CounterPage`
2. Then the user switched to any other app ,(i.e. Instagram,Facebook, etc)
3. Now, when user starts our app again then CounterPage should open

Comment: are you still encountering the issue? I havent't tried it out, but it looks like you are missing the '/' in front of your route name. 

instead of 'counter' use '/counter'. hope this helps